# The "User7ZipPath" parameter is not supported

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Recently, I have been getting this error a lot and from some research, I  got to know that the cause for it is the `Xamarin.Build` package.

The error text is as follows:

**The "User7ZipPath" parameter is not supported by the "XamarinDownloadArchives" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.**

I have tried the solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96703/the-user7zippath-parameter-is-not-supported) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71838/i-got-could-not-find-7zip-exe-in-xamarin-installation-error/p1) but nothing helped.

My configuration is as follows:

`Xamarin version: 4.7.10.38`

`Visual Studio 2015`

The Error occurs when I update the xamarin build NuGet package, If anyone has a solution to this problem please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: So, have you also tried [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Build.Download/0.4.3-beta1)?

Comment: Yes, i did it did not help @JoeLv

Comment: It's strange, it happens sometime when I build iOS shared project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At last after all this time I was able to solve this problem.

The problem was with `Xamarin.Build.Download` package.

Now this package had a problem in version 4.7 where it is unable to find the **XamarinDownloadArchives** task.

I checked a lot of places and for the answer but nothing seemed to help with this issue after that I removed the bin, obj folders for all my projects.

And Updated my `Xamarin.Build.Download` package to version 0.4.11 and everything started working.

I hope this helps someone else, In case of any queries related to this issue feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally! I've come with a solution. The problem was in the `Xamarin.Build.Download` package, v0.4.0. It was a annidated dependency (in iOS) of `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` v2.2.1.

Updating `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` to v2.3.0 (the most recent version as of today) solves the issue. Make sure to clean the solution after update NuGet dependencies, though.

Comment: This particular error i am getting is for Android not ios i solved ios a long time ago so if you have a solution for Android kindly update that too

Comment: No problem mate just help out when you do find out anything @webo80